# TYPO3 RTE-Link with id of linked page as data-atribute or rel-tag?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte

I'm trying to add the special id of the linked page as an rel-attribute to each a-Tag of the RTE.
At the moment, the rel part is include in the link, but with "page:uid" it inserts the actual page ID and NOT the id of the linked page.

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.link {
  typolink.parameter.append < lib.parseFunc.tags.link.typolink.parameter.append
  typolink.ATagParams = rel={page:uid}
  wrap < lib.parseFunc.tags.link.newWrap
}
```

For Example:
The site "Contact" has the ID-number 210 but at the moment, i'm on the "start" page with the id = 11.
Now I have a textlink at the page "start" to the "Contacts" page.
The HTML part looks as follows:

```
<a href="contacts/" rel="11">contact</a>
```

But it should be like this

```
<a href="contacts/" rel="210">contact</a>
```

Or even better like this (with special data-attribute)

```
<a href="contacts/" data-relation="210">contact</a>
```

How can I get this? 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do is a bit tricky in TypoScript, but not impossible. You have to work on the arguments of the pseudo `<link>` tag which look like `162 - some-class ...` - `162` is the page-id in this example.

### TypoScript

```
# Simulating some content
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value (
  <link 162 - some-class>Some page</link>
)

page.10.parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE

# Adjusting parsing instructions for pseudo links
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
  tags.link {
    typolink.ATagParams.append = TEXT
    typolink.ATagParams.append {
      stdWrap {
        # having all link settings "162 - some-class ..."
        data = parameters:allParams
        # split by whitespace
        split.token.char = 32
        # use first item
        split.returnKey = 0
        # enforce integer values
        intval = 1
      }
      noTrimWrap = | data-relation="|"|
    }
  }
}
```

### Generated markup

```
<p class="bodytext">
  <a href="/tests/some-page" class="some-class" data-relation="162">Some page</a>
</p>
```